# Can i merge two collections by specifying index

Tags: underscore.js

```
c1: [{n: "name 1", r: 152},{n: "name 2", r: 153}, {n: "name 6", r: 157}];

c2: [{n: "name 3", r: 154},{n: "name 4", r: 155}, {n: "name 5", r: 156}];
```

I have two collections `c1 and c2` like above. I need to insert c2 values into c1 at `index 2`.

End result should be like this.

```
merged: [{n: "name 1", r: 152},{n: "name 2", r: 153}, {n: "name 3", r: 154},
         {n: "name 4", r: 155}, {n: "name 5", r: 156}, {n: "name 6", r: 157}];
```

I think using [union](http://underscorejs.org/#union) will merge at the start, not at specified index. I need this to be achieved in underscore way.

Comment: Are you talking about Backbone collections or arrays? If it's just arrays, please remove the `backbone.js` tag.

Comment: @loganfsmyth http://underscorejs.org/#collections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will let you add elements to your array :

> **Array splice** array.splice(index , howMany[, element1[, ...[, elementN]]])
>   Changes the content of an array, adding new elements while removing old elements.
>
> *index*
>       Index at which to start changing the array. If greater than the length of the array, no elements will be removed.  If negative, will
>   begin that many elements from the end.
>
> *howMany*
>       An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove.
>
> *element1, ..., elementN*
>       The elements to add to the array. If you don't specify any elements, splice simply removes elements from the array.

To insert a list of elements, you can use [`_.flatten`](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#flatten) to prepare the arguments :

```
var c1 = [{n: "name 1", r: 152}, {n: "name 2", r: 152}, {n: "name 6", r: 152}];
var c2 = [{n: "name 3", r: 152}, {n: "name 4", r: 152}, {n: "name 5", r: 152}];

c1.splice.apply(c1, _.flatten([2, 0, c2]));

console.log(c1);
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/4cbCy/

Or if you prefer to avoid `_.flatten`, you can use

```
var args = c2.slice();
args.unshift(2, 0);
c1.splice.apply(c1, args);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4cbCy/1/

Comment: you are smart. and it is hacky way.. :) so there is no built-in functions for this in underscore?

Comment: So now i have some guts to request this feature on underscore.js core.

Comment: @user10: You can always patch this into your Underscore using [`_.mixin`](http://underscorejs.org/#mixin).

Answer (score 1):

You can use vanilla javascript for that.

```
var c1 =  [{n: "name 1", r: 152},{n: "name 2", r: 153}, {n: "name 6", r: 157}];
var c2 = [{n: "name 3", r: 154},{n: "name 4", r: 155}, {n: "name 5", r: 156}];
var lastPiece = c1.splice(2)//1 based position, rest of array is returned to last. 
/*c1 now contains only r=152, r=153*/
//For is used for brevity use something else if you have things other then objects
for(var i in c2){c1.push(c2[i])}
c1.push(lastPiece[0])//Since this is an array
```

OR

```
   var c1 =  [{n: "name 1", r: 152},{n: "name 2", r: 153}, {n: "name 6", r: 157}];
   var c2 = [{n: "name 3", r: 154},{n: "name 4", r: 155}, {n: "name 5", r: 156}];
   var lastPiece = c1.splice(2)//1 based position, rest of array is returned to last. 
   /*c1 now contains only r=152, r=153*/
   //For is used for brevity use something else if you have things other then objects
   var temp =  c1.concat(c2);
   temp = temp.concat(lastPiece)
   console.log(temp)
```

Some [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/underscore-vs-vanilla) can be interesting. It crushes on the splice.apply

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but it is hard to change lib from underscore.

Comment: @user10 this requires no additional libs.

Comment: @quinnirill sorry i didn't read this answer completely. Second one (or patr) looks good.

Comment: definitely deserves +1. @ramm86, i really like the second block.

Comment: what if c1 has 10 items and if i need to insert c2 at index 5. As per your first block it needs 2 looping.